# Cannot deploy iOS app to App Store though Xcode is latest

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, app-store, app-store-connect

I am trying to deploy an iOS app to the AppStore but I am getting following error;

> Apps and app updates submitted to the App Store must be built with Xcode 5.1.1 or later, and iOS 7 SDK.

I am constantly facing this problem although I am using Xcode 6.4 and target SDK 8.0. For time being I installed Xcode 7 beta version but later on I uninstalled beta version. I am wondering if beta version is interfering with the build process.

Comment: You target SDK8.0 and the error says you need to target SDK7. They're different. What's expected behavior for you?

Comment: Why are you using SDK 8.0 and not SDK 8.4 which comes with Xcode 6.4?

Comment: 8.0 is deployment target. Setting deployment target to 8.4 doesn't fix the problem either.

Comment: @gonbe, shouldn't I use the latest SDK used by most of iOS users? BTW I have successfully deployed apps to App Store. This problem just appeared recently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am facing the same issue. It seems the issue is because you are on OS X El Capitan. See this: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/8841. It seems Apple has started to reject binaries from XCode 6.4 on El Capitan which they were accepting before. I think the only solution is to downgrade to Yosamite, re install latest XCode and then submit!

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the problem. Thank you for the solution.